# upload base64 image to filestack

Tags: angularjs, base64, angular8, filestack

I am using filestack in angular 8 and I want to upload a base64 image to filestack and then want a filestack response so I can use that file URL to another place. 
please help me.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: hello @NilankaManoj, let me share my code with you [http://prntscr.com/s339xk] [http://prntscr.com/s33ab9] [http://prntscr.com/s33bmy] [http://prntscr.com/s33cka]